# Enderman Containment

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If i make the wall three blocks thick, and make water on the ceiling, would I be able to contain many endermen in a giant end stone room?  I am doing this for an adventure map so I need the answer for the final boss battle.

Answer (score 1):

Endermen will teleport to any block within 32 blocks in each axis. While it will not spawn or teleport on\to blocks that has lava or water on them. This means you can't really contain them to one smaller area. It's not unusual that they can teleport multiple times quickly.

In other words, unless you use a mod, you can't really contain it. Only way I can think of without mods is making a massive, flat area with loads of water\lava and no real places for it to teleport. It can't spawn nor teleport to\in areas 2 blocks or lower.

Comment: I don't agree with this as you can create a room and make sure that within 32 blocks there are no valid spawnpoints for them, either by making the surrounding area two high or by placing water where you cant do this, then the enderman will only teleport in their initial room

Comment: Its the same concept behind ender farms as you wouldn't want them teleporting away there either

Comment: I don't think you see the point completely. If the enderman moves 32 blocks in the X direction, you need another 32 blocks to prevent it from moving another 32 blocks in X direction. So if you got a 5x5 room, you need to surround that with 37 blocks in each direction, including diagonal.

In other words, it can be contained, but it's hard to pull off effectively. And it can not be contained in a (example) 5*5 box surrounded by 1'ish block of lava.

Comment: No for an enderman to teleport he needs a block to teleport to he will not be able to teleport to space. see episode 300 of Ethos lets play

Comment: Well, ok. If you made a flat world where top layer was water or lava, you could make a room whatever size you wanted, with maybe some water or lava on top to prevent it from teleporting to the roof. For making it in an ocean on a regular level, you'd need to make sure there were no caves it could teleport to 32 or less blocks under the room.

Answer (score 0):

Technically yes, but they might teleport away, since they randomly do that.

> Endermen always initially spawn in pairs, but will often appear individually or in larger groups due to **random teleportation.**

Source: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enderman

Comment: I think that was the problem he was trying to address - keeping endermen in a room in spite of the teleportation.
I believe if you make the walls sufficiently thick they will be unable to teleport, but I think it will need to be more than 10 blocks - not totally sure how far they can teleport.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to simply spawn them in using a clock and command block. While your setup *should* keep most of them in the area, they can teleport away randomly (as Dylan noted). In Vanilla, that's about as good as you can get.

If you are able to install the Extra Utilities mod, as well as one of the various mods that allows you to create helper NPCs with melee capabilities, then you could have a turtle hit them with "The Ender" sword as they spawn, which prevents teleportation on the first hit - but would weaken each by about 6 - 8 health.

Best advice, make sure there's no fire *or* water in the space you intend to spawn them, because wandering into either is going to cause them to instantly teleport away. Just keep re-stocking them with a redstone clock for the duration that you need to.

Comment: I don't know the Extra Utilities mod, but through commands I have given myself an enchanted sword with a sharpness level so high that it actually doesn't do any damage, it said "Sharpness -32xxx", so if you could get The Ender sword with that enchantment they wouldn't take any damage.